# Garbage data after stackalloc field initializer

Tags: c#, performance, stackalloc

I am using .NET 6.0 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2022 last Version, last Build, and this code runs fine and even **SEEMINLGY** does what I want: have a look:

[image]

But: keep a closer look on the "`Init(in ReadonlySpan<Char> a)`"
I can assign my new(a) to the nodes[0], no error or whatever. But when I do, the nodes[0] has STILL garbage data in and I cannot store my type in that [0] field of the stackallocated span field?

Is this a bug in .NET 6.0 or am I doing smth bad/wrong?

Pls help!

Ok here the exact code:

```
public ref struct MyType
{
 private Span<RefType> nodes = stackalloc RefType[30];  
    
     public unsafe  struct RefType
     {
          public char* data;
          public int length;
          public RefType(in CharSpan a)
          {
             //AsRef(span) is a private method, which gives me back a valid pointer to the span, this works ok in my code! dont bother to much with this
             data = Unsafe.AsPointer(ref GetRefTo(s))
             length = a.Length;
          }
     }

public unsafe MyType()
{
    nodes.Clear();
}

public unsafe void Init(in ReadOnlySpan<char> a)
{
    //nodes[0] = new(a); //this does not work!
    //this does not work aswell!
    nodes[0].data = Unsafe.AsPointer(ref MemoryMarshal.GetRef(a));
    nodes[0].length = a.Length;
    Console.WriteLine(*nodes[0].data + "        " + 
                                         nodes[0].length);
}

public string DoWork()
{
    //Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return nodes[0].ToString();
}
```

}

Comment: There's no such thing as `Bug` in .Net, but your question to me is unclear! What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Transcendent I try to allocate in my ref-struct type a big chunk of data for some more performant computation and it shall live as long as my ref-type lives :)

Comment: It shall not escape the lifetime of my type, cause there will be alot of math operations going on in this type but only for the lifetime of the ref-struct, so the data shall be fully discarded after the function returns, who held my ref-struct type.  But also, the stackalloc shall not be only usable in a function , but as i said, live as long my ref type lives.

Comment: Do you know about OS Stack Size? If I were you I would not do this.

Comment: i mean, 100 is abit to much, i actually need only 30 ^^. Wanted to test the limits.. But still mate, it does not work? the data in there is garbage? this is a bug in my eyes?

Comment: Please post your code instead of the screen shot. I need to run and debug it to see what is going on.

Comment: thx first for ur fast help!! much respect and appreciation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242878/discussion-between-shpendicus-and-transcendent).

Comment: There are some missing types here: `CharSpan` and `Node`, please add relevant code

Comment: CharSpan = using System.ReadonlySpan<char>                                                                       there is no "Node" type, its my "RefType" struct, which is a span, and was as the name suggest, actusally to be used as a ref struct but since we cant use it in generic, i only use normal struct. you can do my testcode with any basic type. Stil same issue. And I have to say, that I would suggest to avoid that code, its hard buggy.

Comment: RefType = unsafe struct, not span, my bad..